# multinomial model with some certain parameters

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis, multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

I might be asking a naive questions here, sorry.

Imaging I have 4 categories, each one has a probability of $\theta_i$ being selelcted, $i=1..4$ and sum of $\theta_i$ is 1. For this simple multinomial model I can use a 4-dimensional Dirichlet distribution to capture the 4 unkown parameters $\theta_i$, then after observing data, I can Bayesian inference $\theta_i$  simply via conjugacy. Everything is good so far.

But what if I know, say $\theta_1=0.1,\theta_2=0.2$ for certain and $\theta_3, \theta_4$ are the only two parameters that I am not sure. How can I Bayesian inference those two in this case, since a 2-dimentional Dirichlet prior seems cannot be used... what other parameteric family of multivaraite distribution can fit in my case.

Thanks, hope the quesiton is making sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can simplify the problem by removing categories 1 and 2 from it altogether.  This leaves you with categories 3 and 4 only, both in terms of $\theta$ and in terms of the data.  (After all, learning that, say, $x_1 = 1$ given that you already know $\theta_1 = 0.1$ gives you no additional information about $\theta_3$).  You construct a new parameter $p_3 = \theta_3/(1-\theta_1-\theta_2)$, and, obviously, $p_4 = 1 - p_3$.  These represent the conditional probabilities of seeing category 3 and 4 respectively given that you've seen either category 3 or category 4.

You now have a binomial distribution and can use the beta distribution for your prior, as it's the one-parameter form of the Dirichlet.  When you've calculated the posterior for $p_3$, you can make the obvious transforms of $\theta_3 = (1-\theta_1-\theta_2)p_3$ and $\theta_4 = (1-\theta_1-\theta_2)(1-p_3)$ to find the posteriors for $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$.

Comment: If you like it, please accept it - it helps other readers know the question has been successfully answered.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I just realised that I have another very related question, could you also please have look at this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349331/multinomial-distribution-aggregation-property thanks!